# How Can I Launch an iOS app built with Titanium in the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus Simulators?

Tags: ios, ios8, titanium, ios-simulator, titanium-mobile

I typically use the Titanium CLI to build my project using a command like the following:

```
ti build --skip-js-minify -p ios -T simulator -Y iphone --retina --tall --sim64btin
```

Now that Titanium 3.4 SDK is out and supports iOS 8 and XCode 6, I expected that I would be able to easily launch my app in the new simulators.  But currently it seems to be defaulting to the iPhone 4s sim.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, including importing the .xcodeproj into XCode, but I find my way to be more convenient personally.  It's not perfect, but this is what I'm currently doing, and how I got there.

Some inspection of the Titanium SDK source reveals that the CLI uses a binary called `ios-sim` to actually launch the simulator.  Some googling will reveal that this is a node.js package.  I happened to have this installed, but I'm not sure if it was installed by Titanium or not - the build script uses a binary that is packaged in the SDK.
Console output:

```
RalphsMBP:~ trey$ which ios-sim
/Users/trey/npm/bin//ios-sim
RalphsMBP:~ trey$ ios-sim --version
2.0
```

The documentation says this about Xcode6:

> Supports Xcode 6 only since version 3.x.

So step 1:

```
sudo npm install -g ios-sim@3.0
ios-sim --version
```

You should now be at 3.0.0.

My first thought was to replace the binary in the Titanium SDK with the newly installed binary from npm.  I thought that perhaps the arguments to `ti build` would be passed directly to ios-sim.  This turned out to be a dead end (The builder.py script is a mess in my opinion - rewrite it already!)

Fortunately it's still pretty easy to write a build script to launch in your simulator of choice using the new `devicetypeid` option to ios-sim.  Use `ios-sim showdevicetypes` to get a list of valid device type ids. This is my iPhone 6 build script:

```
ti build -b --skip-js-minify -p ios && ios-sim launch ${project_path}/build/iphone/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/${project_base_name}.app --devicetypeid com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6
```

The variables are part of the sublime text build system, but you can apply the concept any way you want.  The -b flag is --build-only, and I think the rest is pretty self explanatory.